# Clearing only specific cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies

How can I clear only two cookies using JavaScript?

I use the below code to set these cookies.

```
function setCookie(c_name, value, exdays)
{
    var exdate = new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value = escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : ";expires=" + exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value;
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A cookie is expired if the *Expires* parameter value is a date in the past. So just set the value to a date in the past:

```
function deleteCookie(c_name) {
    document.cookie = encodeURIComponent(c_name) + "=deleted; expires=" + new Date(0).toUTCString();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

use the same function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays), passing exdays = -1. That will set expiry date to yesterday.