# How to delete the sessionid from browser's cookie store

Tags: javascript, browser, sessionid, jsessionid

I want to logout my web App in browser when click the logout button.And want to implement it just with js code.So,there's no logout servlet. That means,i need to delete the sessionid which is used now and stored in browser memory,but how can I do the same?

Answer (score 11):

1. All your session cookies should be httpOnly for security reasons. This would ensure the cookies are not accessible in javascript and would reduce the risk in case of XSS attach. Which also means that the cookie cannot be just cleared at client side.
2. When the user clicks logout, you may be interested in clearing the server side resources. At least for that you should be hitting the server.

With the above being said. I would recommend you make an AJAX call to your servlet and which can clear your cookie as well as free up server side resources allocated for that session.

If you are still not convinced and have to clear the cookie using javascript please refer to SO question [delete cookies using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5976912/clear-cookies-using-javascript)

Comment: Thanks!I have resovled it.My method is that get my cookie's JSESSIONID,and make it to be 123; The cookie's path is the key point. For Example ,the js code is: document.cookie="JSESSIONID=123;Path=/managerconsole;"